# Permission denied rm a symlink I own on OSX 10

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

The output below confirms to me that "emp1" the current user own the symlink "npm", thus I should be able to rwx all day if I want to.

Why am I getting Permission denied when trying to remove it?  Thanks

```
~$ whoami
empl1
~$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 empl1  staff  38 26 Dec 16:02 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
~$ rm /usr/local/bin/npm 
rm: /usr/local/bin/npm: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only users with write access to a directory can remove its content. In your case you can check with `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` who the owner of this directory is. And than either switch to this user or use `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm` to remove the link.

Comment: The directory is owned by "admin" so I did the command you suggested but got back "Password: Sorry, try again." with correct admin password typed.

Comment: You need to type your own password. If your user doesn't have admin rights, you need to log in as an admin user first.

Comment: When I type emp1 password, I get "empl1 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.",  I want emp1 just to do this task and not to give permanent higher privilege.

Comment: On a standard OSX installation only admin users can use sudo. So there is no way around switching users here (which is a 1 minute task if you have Fast User Switching enabled in System Preferences).